# pod repo update failed: Cannot do hard reset with paths

Tags: git, cocoapods, repo

When I'm running

```
proxychains4 pod repo update
```

I got the following output

```
[proxychains] config file found: /usr/local/Cellar/proxychains-ng/4.10/etc/proxychains.conf
[proxychains] preloading /usr/local/Cellar/proxychains-ng/4.10/lib/libproxychains4.dylib
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.10
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.10
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.10
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.10
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.10
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.10
Updating spec repo `master`
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.10
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.10
[proxychains] Strict chain  ...  127.0.0.1:1080  ...  api.github.com:443  ...  OK
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.10
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.10
  $ /usr/local/bin/git -C /Users/linxi/.cocoapods/repos/master fetch origin
  [proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.10
  [proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.10
  [proxychains] Strict chain  ...  127.0.0.1:1080  ...  github.com:443  ...  OK
  [proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.10
  [proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.10
  [proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.10
  From https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs
     1eaabbe..7cc75a2  master     -> origin/master
  [proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.10
  $ /usr/local/bin/git -C /Users/linxi/.cocoapods/repos/master rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
  [proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.10
  master
  $ /usr/local/bin/git -C /Users/linxi/.cocoapods/repos/master reset --hard origin/master [proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.10
  [proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.10
  fatal: Cannot do hard reset with paths.
[!] CocoaPods was not able to update the `master` repo. If this is an unexpected issue and persists you can inspect it running `pod repo update --verbose`
```

However, if I run git manually

```
proxychains4 /usr/local/bin/git -C /Users/linxi/.cocoapods/repos/master reset --hard origin/master
```

Everything works well.

I have to use proxychains to connect github.

I'm running cocoapods version 1.2.0/git version 2.7.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like proxychains's commandline output somehow mixed in the cocoapods's script.

Add -q option to make proxychains run quietly fixes this problem.

`proxychains4 -q pod repo update`